# How to integrate tesseract-ocr library in a CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: c++, ocr, tesseract, ros

I have no idea of how to integrate the tesseract-ocr library to my ros project, I use qt creator to code and the library is correctly installed since Qtcreator autocompletes the lines where i use the library but this code fails to compile

```
#include "text_detector.h"
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>

image_transport::Subscriber sub;
image_transport::Publisher imPub;
ros::Publisher textPub;
tesseract::TessBaseAPI tess;

void onImageReceived(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg){

}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
    ros::init(argc,argv,"text_detector");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("Starting text detection");
    image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
    imPub = it.advertise("camera_hsv",1);
    tess.Init(NULL,"eng",tesseract::OEM_DEFAULT);
    sub = it.subscribe("camera_raw",1,&onImageReceived);
   // textPub=nh.advertise<>("text",1000);
    ros::spin();
}
```

with this compilation error

> text_detector.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `tesseract::TessBaseAPI::TessBaseAPI()'
>   text_detector.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to`tesseract::TessBaseAPI::~TessBaseAPI()'

How can i add the library to the project in the CMakeLists.txt?
Thanks!

Comment: is your code/project available on git?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are not linking the library. Your `CMakeLists.txt` should contain

```
target_link_libraries (<YOUR-EXECUTABLE-NAME>  tesseract)
```

Depending on your CMake file  might just be `${PROJECT_NAME}`